# Using axios.post it is unable to fetch url in web.php and showing"The server has not found matching the requested URI"in console

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, http-status-code-404

Actually im trying to clone Instagram following and followes using axios.post

this is my FollowButton.vue

```
<template>
    <div >

   <button  class="btn btn-primary  " @click="followUser">Follow</button>



    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props:['userId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        methods:{
          followUser(){

             axios.post('/follow/'+ this.userId).then(response=>{

                 alert(response.data);
             });
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my web.php. I want axios to reach at this route and return the response

> success

```
Route::post('/follow/{user}', function(){

    return ['success'];
});
```

This is in my index.blade.php whole on clicking it passes user-id to followbutton.vue

```
 <flw-button user-id="{{$user->id}}"></flw-button> </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `user.id` is being set properly?

Comment: @Cyrus yes im sure

Comment: Can you check console if there's any js error?

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak im getting "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost/follow/2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" @click.prevent="followUser">Follow</button>`

Comment: Same error on clicking follow button in the console:"HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost/follow/2"